# pfsense inter vlan slow speed

Tags: vlan, bandwidth, pfsense, slow-connection

In our company we use pfsesne 2.3 as a router.
Problem is with inter-vlan transfer, which is very slow about 150kbit/s in both ways.
Its very strange , network is 1GB , transfers inside vlan's are god (full 1GB), just only transfer between computers in one vlan to another computers in second vlan is extremely low.
We do not use any filer, no traffic shaper.

Can someon help mi or guide me what can be wrong ?

Regards

Comment: Is this on a physical machine or a VM? Please post the output of `ethtool -k {int}` for every interface. Is MTU settings correct on every networking piece? (taking into account the VLAN headers on trunk ports for example)

Comment: This is a vm machine on xenserver.
I knew this problem of pfsense and xenserver 
[link] (https://forum.pfsense.org/index.php?topic=85797.0) and this parameter has been  set  on every pfsense interface
 xe vif-param-set uuid=VIFUUID other-config:ethtool-tx="off"

On pfsense there is no command ethtool.